# Which is better between Ionic and Titanium and why?

Tags: android, ionic2, titanium, appcelerator

I did some research but couldn't really pin-point and couldn't really come to a conclusion on which one to use and why? Would appreciate some helpful links and differences that can help me reach on a conclusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ionic uses web-based technology. You're basically building a website in a native wrapper. You're still building the app in html/css/js and it will be shipped as such. You might have access to a couple of the native functionalities but that doesn't make an Ionic app a native one.

Titanium is a hybrid technology. You write your code in javascript. Through a layer this javascript talks to native components. So if you make a "Window" in javascript it natively is translated to a window object in Android/iOS. It then also behaves completely native because it actually is. It is as performant as native, as it is native. You just control it with javascript in the background. A well made Titanium app is indistinguishable from a truly native app.

In core, thats the difference.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. So I need a proper app, long-term, with access to all features, etc.. I should go for Titanium.

Comment: Correct. Titanium is much more stable and smooth as opposed to Ionic. But be aware, since there is a translation layer in between your code and native (on all platforms like these) you're limited to what the layer provides in terms of API's. Look at the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/) to see what is possible. I guess the feature set with Titanium is bigger than the Ionic

Answer (score 2):

Titanium uses (like RN) the proxy pattern. The app is in runtime a real native app without limitations. Ionic uses phonegap/cordova under the hood. This is web technology. The webview and especially the used framework consumes a lot of battery and traffic. the performance is suboptimal because web is a universal machine.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: it is an answer, not a question